# Unable to run C# exe from Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, containers

Following is my Dockerfile code. I'm trying to run a C# console application which is an EXE file. I created a sample application with same code, and it works, but this one is an existing application which is not running i.e., when I try to run `docker logs <thiscontainer>` it won't show any result.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY bin/ MbrRst/
WORKDIR MbrRst/Release
ENTRYPOINT ["RunAccessApp.exe"]
```

The only difference I see between the sample application and actual application is the `TargetFramework` in the `project properties`.

My actual application has .NET Framework 4.5.2, and the other one (sample) has .NET Core 3.1.

I think I need to use the right mcr link in the Dockerfile. Please help me out :)

Comment: Did you try to google for .NET FW docker image? It'll lead you to [.NET FW docker repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework) with Windows based images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is .Net Framework, you need to use the right image in the docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5
```